# Cyrillic letters come as "???" - php

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, cyrillic

Okay so with php i add text in a database. Looking through phpmyadmin, i can see how the letters (which are cyrillic) are displayed correctly, therefore i assume i am writing them in the database in the correct way without any problems.

However, when i then visualise them on the same page where i added the text, it comes as "???" (just question marks).
I've tried changing the html meta tag. Currently it's "utf-8"" and i've tried with "windows-1251" as well but still with no success.

Everything in phpmyadmin is changed to utf-8 and ive tried all possible solutions that I've found so far.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You can try to run this query before your query:

SET NAMES utf8;

Comment: This is purely a guess. The whole ecosystem has to be in UTF8 to work. Even if this did work, it's a band-aid. Something isn't getting UTF8